# OpenCV - Color correction matrix not preserving white i.e columns do not sum to 1

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, color-space

The OpenCV contrib has a [mcc](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/dc1/tutorial_ccm_color_correction_model.html) module that can generate color correction matrix.

By giving an image as an input to the module one can set parameters like error metric, gamma, color space weights etc to calculate a CCM .

Now here is the problem. The OpenCV generates a CCM that has no preservation of white. White is preserved only when the generated ccm has columns of its 3x3 or 3x4 matrix sum to 1.

Does anybody has any idea to how can we force opencv's mcc module to generate CCMs that sum to 1?

Comment: It seems that the algorimth they are using won't set the white balance, you can do it yoursel afterwards by normalicing the image channles

Comment: White balancing is not the same as white preservation. For my case I am using a white balanced image for the generation of CCM.

Comment: Can you post sample CCM results from imatest  - with sum 1 and without sum 1? I want to check if there is a simple way to compute one from the other. Please select linear color space (without gamma).

Comment: I am a bit confused. There are two similar options. One is "Assume linear input, apply matrix, apply color space gamma". The other is "Assume linear input and output (gamma = 1) throughout".  Which one to select?

Comment: Also by selecting the first option the results are: Without sum to 1 = [1.17 -0.30 -0.05; -0.31 1.39 -0.62; -0.19 -0.39 1.35] and by sum to 1 = [1.28 -0.55 -0.21; 0.00 2.11 -0.48; -0.29 -0.56 1.69]. (; indicates a row change)

Comment: The options are strange - in both cases the input is linear. The standard image processing pipeline is "apply matrix, apply color space gamma". The options probably select between minimization functions. With/Without sum to 1 probably also selects different minimization functions. The corrected colors are going to look different.